unable to install the `chowtest` package in Google Colab
I would like to apply structural  break test in python, so here is my  colab page  structure:

But it generates following error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'chowtest/setup.py'
Hint: It looks like a path. The path does exist.

I can't even install chowtest in pycharm, was it oudated or what is the source of the issue?

Did you mean !pip install chowtest? Or rather !pip install ., since you already changed directory into chowtest?

ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found. this error

What is in chowtest? It seems it is not the Git repository you wanted to clone, because the cloning failed, because the directory already existed and there was something else in it.

If you do not wish to modify the source code for the library, you can just install the package from GitHub using
pip install git+https://github.com/jkclem/chowtest

However, on the other hand, there is a problem in the setup.py of the repo. The package sklearn was changed to scikit-learn, you will have to manually change that in the setup.py. That should fix the problem.


still it has some problem

Can you be more specific?

i solved it by my way, when i  am posting here questions, some guys randomly closing questions  without  asking if thei efford  helps me or not, it is  children garden habit and not serious stuff done by adult person,i think stackoverflow moderators should work on it
